# Getting too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation compile error while defining lambda inside assert (assert.h) in Xcode [c++]

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, lambda, macros

I am using assertion macro from assert.h
I have defined lambda to perform assertion checking.

```
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 1;

const auto check = [val1,val2]()-> bool
{
    return val1 < val2;
};
// no error for this call
assert(check() && "Test is failed");

// no error for this call
assert([=]()-> bool
       {
           return val1 < val2;
       }() && "Test is failed");
```

> ```
> //compile error for this call "too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation"
> assert([val1,val2]()-> bool
>        {
>            return val1 < val2;
>        }() && "Test is failed");
> ```

why I am getting

> too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

compile error for the case when I am using assert macro and defining lambda with more than one argument in the capture list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the comma in the capture list.

The preprocessor has an extremely limited understanding of the C++ syntax, it mainly does trivial text substitution. If a comma is not between matching inner parenthesis (and not part of a token like a string literal of course), the preprocessor will treat it as a separator of arguments of the macro invocation.

So the preprocessor thinks you are invoking assert with the two arguments `[this` and the rest of the stuff behind the first comma, which yields the error.

You can fix this error by using an extra set of parenthesis:

```
int i = -7, j = 7;
assert(([i,j](){return i + j;}()));
```

---

For the standard lovers:

> The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses forms the list of
>   arguments for the function-like macro. **The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma
>   preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate
>   arguments.** If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise
>   act as preprocessing directives,155 the behavior is undefined.

16.3/11 in N4140, emphasis mine.

Comment: Baum mit Augen still one thing not clear, the argument of assert in asert.h is inside ()
`#define assert(e) \
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)`

Comment: @TM Those parens come too late, for the quote above, the parens and commas *before* the expansion are relevant, not those in the result.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor is very simple, it sees all commas as argument separators.

So you can't use a macro if you pass in anything with a comma as argument to the macro.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg why it is not throwing compile error for other commas in case of call with [=]?

Comment: @TM To be brutally honest I don't think you're telling us the truth. The preprocessor have no concept or knowledge of actual C++ code or C++ syntax, the preprocessor only knows its own limited language, where all commas in a macro "call" are used as argument separators. Therefore I don't believe that code will work and not give you an error.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg but it works :) without any compile error I am using Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

Comment: It really does work. ;) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bacaff636efa183 Macros understand the "function call syntax", but not the lambda capture syntax.

Comment: That's weird, works for me too in GCC 5.2.1. It *shouldn't* work though. The problem seems to be the comma in the capture list. I'll have to check the standard to see if they changed anything with C++11 to make the preprocessor more intelligent.

Comment: *"The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma
preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate
arguments."* 16.3/11 in N4140. So gcc seems to be correct. Was that not the case pre-C++XX? If so, for what XX?