# Google test (gtest) `EXPECT_TRUE()` macro won't compile with `std::is_same<>` template as input

Tags: c++, templates, macros, googletest, is-same

In C++17 with clang compiler, I get the same build errors whether I do this:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);
```

or this:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(typename std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);,
```

or this:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(typename std::is_same_v<typename decltype(var1), typename decltype(var2)>);
```

Build command:

```
bazel test //my_target_dir:my_target
```

Build error:

> ```
> error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
>                 decltype(var2)>);
>                 ^
> gtest/gtest.h:1980:9: note: macro 'EXPECT_TRUE' defined here
> #define EXPECT_TRUE(condition) \
>         ^
> myfile.cpp:125:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXPECT_TRUE'
>     EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_same_v<
>     ^
> ```

Note that the Googletest definition for `EXPECT_TRUE()` is here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L1980.

**What is wrong with what I'm doing, and how can I get this to compile?**

### References:

1. [`std::is_same<T, U>::value` and `std::is_same_v<T, U>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)
2. [GoogleTest (gtest) documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest/docs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Summary

This does NOT work, because the C++ preprocessor which processes macros was written before templates existed, and sees the comma as separating two separate arguments to the macro. It thinks I have called the `EXPECT_TRUE()` macro with `anything<foo` as the 1st argument, and `bar>` as the 2nd argument:

```cpp
// This does NOT work, because the preprocessor sees this 1 template
// argument to the macro as two separate arguments separated by the
// comma
EXPECT_TRUE(anything<foo, bar>);
```

These options DO work:

```cpp
// Option 1: move the template outside of the macro call
bool isSameType = std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>;
EXPECT_TRUE(isSameType);

// Option 2: for this particular case I can instead use the 
// `static_assert()` function in place of the `EXPECT_TRUE()` macro
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);

// Option 3: use double parenthesis to force the macro to treat
// the parameter containing comma-separated template parameters
// as a **single argument** to the macro:
EXPECT_TRUE((std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>));
```

### Details

After spending some time chatting with some friends, one of them, [Drew Gross](https://www.linkedin.com/in/drewgross), explained the following:

> Due to the C++ preprocessor model, commas within a template instantiation are interpreted as separating arguments of the macro, not arguments of the template. This is one of the many reasons that using macros is heavily discouraged in modern C++. So when you write:
>
> ```
> SOME_MACRO(some_template<a, b>());
> ```
>
> it's interpreted as passing 2 arguments to `SOME_MACRO`, the first being `some_template<a`, and the second being `b>()`. Since `EXPECT_TRUE` only accepts a single argument, this fails to compile.
>
> In this particular case I'd recommend using `static_assert` instead of `EXPECT_TRUE`. If the thing you were testing wasn't a compile time constant, you would have to assign to a local variable first, e.g.
>
> ```
> bool localVar = some_template<a, b>();
> EXPECT_TRUE(localVar);
> ```

He's spot-on correct. Since the C and C++ macro preprocessor was written PRIOR to C++ existing, it does not recognize the C++ `<` and `>` template scoping symbols (it thinks they are just "less than" and "greater than" symbols, respectively), so in this statement (`EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);`), it sees the comma and parses `std::is_same_v<decltype(var1)` as the 1st argument to the gtest `EXPECT_TRUE()` macro, and `decltype(var2)>` as a 2nd argument to the macro.

Therefore, here's the solution:

```
bool isSameType = std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>;
EXPECT_TRUE(isSameType);
```

As Drew states, however, a better solution is to just use `static_assert()` in this case instead of gtest's `EXPECT_TRUE()`, since this test can be completed at compile-time rather than run-time:

(better solution):

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);
```

<sub>Note: message not required for `static_assert()` in C++17. [See here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)</sub>

I did some additional research and experimenting, and also discovered that extra parenthesis solve it too. Using extra parenthesis forces the preprocessor to recognize the whole input argument as 1 argument to the macro, since *the preprocessor respects parenthesis* but *doesn't respect template `<>` symbols at all since it isn't template-aware*.

Therefore, this works too:

```
EXPECT_TRUE((std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>));
```

*If in doubt, parenthesize it out. If in need, parenthesis, indeed.* :)

So, now we have 3 viable solutions to this problem. I'd probably go with the `static_assert()` option as my primary solution, and the extra parenthesis option just above as my solution if I needed some template input to be tested during run-time.

### Additional References:

Once I knew what the nature of the problem was (the macro preprocessor seeing the comma and not recognizing C++ template `<` and `>` scoping operators), I was able to do some Googling and find the following answers to look at too:

1. [Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030048/too-many-arguments-provided-to-function-like-macro-invocation)
2. [Getting too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation compile error while defining lambda inside assert (assert.h) in Xcode [c++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957357/getting-too-many-arguments-provided-to-function-like-macro-invocation-compile-er)

<sub>Keywords: macro watch out for template parameter inputs; comma argument delimiter to C/C++ macro preprocessor, c++ extra parenthesis required in macros around macro parameters</sub>